# Copying SharePoint 2010 Site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to copy a SharePoint 2010 site (not site collection) that keeps the workflows attached to the lists and libraries?

I've used the Export-SPWeb/Import-SPWeb tools in PowerShell and it copies everything (groups, workflows, lists, libraries, content, etc.) but my workflows are not associated with the document library they are associated to on the original site and are also not linked to the Tasks and Workflow History lists.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?
Is there no way to do this?
Or, most likely, do I not have enough experience with SharePoint to know the right questions to ask of the Google?

Answer (score 0):

If they are code workflows, I would suggest to package them as solution and redeploy on the target server. If they are sharepoint designer workflows, check the solution mentioned in the below links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/05ebe908-9574-401b-8baf-21ddcf5d8edf

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar problem. I export using Export-SPWeb and upon import on the same site collection and new web I am missing all Tasks. I've noticed the custom list is missing the workflow also. 
The workflow was developed in VS.

You mention:

> If they are code workflows, I would suggest to package them as
>   solution and redeploy on the target server

How and what do I package?

Thanks